Have Microsoft disabled the ability to set logon credentials for certain services, like Windows Update?
I'm pretty sure the following used to work for setting Windows Update to logon as the Guest user from an admin command prompt:
sc.exe config "Windows Update" obj= ".\Guest"

However, that now gives me:
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

The service absolutely does exist under that name, so has sc.exe been prevented from changing the logon credentials for certain services now?  Is there any way that it can be done from an admin command prompt?
